# problem while text editing in android

Tags: android

I have a edittext field in my android. When I am editing cursor showing only one letter. But when I press back key its showing all letters. What to do to show letters while typing.
my layout would be like this:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/conPW"
android:layout_width="248px"
android:layout_height="43px"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:password="true"
android:layout_x="20px"
android:layout_y="152px"
>
</EditText>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: This is a mess... You should read documentation on layouts first.

Comment: Also, forget the closing tag and just close the EditText tag with />. This practice will make cleaner code and in the long run, reduce size a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Ehh...you're setting `android:password="true"` - this is the field that gives you only one letter shown at the time.

Just remove that if you don't want it to function in this fashion?

Also, I would really not be using pixels as your layouts width & height, but that's for you to decide. It's not good practice in terms of different screen resolutions and whatnot. Use wrap_content / fill_parent and dp or sp.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

[What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

Comment: hey I have wrote same layout for another password field its working fine. But I donno what happened to this...?

Comment: @Shekhar You're not being clear in what your problem is......Sigh. Did you even **TRY** to do what I said?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the coding issue. It is a Android emulator issue. Have you tested it on device?